# Junit test cases for hibernate

Tags: hibernate, struts2, junit4, testcase

I have developed a web project(struts2+hibernate) for which i need to do code coverage.I dont know how to write junit test cases for this Hibernate part.Can anyone suggest me idea.i want my test case to check my database if i give input which are not in the database it should through error.
I use eclipse-indigo,Mysql database thanks in advance

```
 package proj.dao.impl;
    import java.util.List; 
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;
    import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.SessionTarget;
    import com.googlecode.s2hibernate.struts2.plugin.annotations.TransactionTarget;
    import proj.dao.EmployeeDAO;
    import proj.model.Employee;

    public class EmployeeDAOImp  implements EmployeeDAO{

        @SessionTarget
        Session session;

        @TransactionTarget
        Transaction transaction; 

        //return all the Employees in list
        public List<Employee> listEmployee(){

            return session.createQuery("from Employee").list();

        }

    }
```

EmployeeDAOImplTest.java

```
package proj.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;
import proj.dao.EmployeeDAO;
import proj.dao.impl.EmployeeDAOImp;
public class EmployeeDAOImplTest {
    @Test
    public void testListEmployee() {
        EmployeeDAO dbo = new EmployeeDAOImp();
        assertTrue("There were no errors in Register", dbo.listEmployee().size()!=0);

    }

}
```

This separate test case only

Null pointer exception pointing to the actual listemployee method inside that DAOImpl class

Comment: Idea: write some test class and call your DAO methods from there.

Comment: @Aleksandr M i tried dont why its not working

Comment: Show what you have tried. What exactly is not working?

Comment: Edit your question, do NOT put code in comments.

Comment: @Aleksandr M edited check

Comment: Hmm... You missed the first step of the "Idea"! 1. Write some test class. :)

Comment: @Aleksandr M i wrote test case only It should work i dont know y it didnt

Comment: What are you actually trying to test here?

Comment: @Dave Newton well for code coverage we need to traverse all our code to get maximum percentage.i was expecting this would check the database and listemployee would return a non-zero value and which inturn returns true for assertTrue ststement thereby a pass testcase